how to add a class, fetch it and return when needed
I want a class where I can pass in an entity that inherits DbContext, and later be able to fetch the entity and pass it to AddDbContext when configuring the site.
I just made a little class to demonstrate what I'm looking for.
Is this the right way or should I do something different?
public class DB<TEntity> : AppFeatureBase where TEntity : DbContext
{
    private readonly DbContext _db;
    private readonly string _conn;

    public DB(string connectionStringName) : base(Features.DB)
    {
        _db = TEntity;
        _conn = connectionStringName;
    }

    public DbContext Context => _db;
    public string ConnectionStringName => _conn;
}

Just for demo, this is how I configure the site:
AssetsConfig.AddAssets(bld,
    new DefaultRoute("Hest", "Index"),
    new Minify(MinifyTargets.Production),
    new SSL()
    new DB<HestContext>("Defalt"));

And this if the actual config:
if (features.FeatureExists(Features.DB))
{
    DB feat = features.Single(feat => feat.Type == Features.DB);
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<DB.Context>(opt => {
        opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(feat.ConnectionStringName));
    });
}

here I pass in HesteContext and I want to use it when configuring

Well a first issue Im seeing here, is that _db = TEntity; cant really work. TEntity will be a class/type that either is DbContext or is derived from DbContext. TEntity however is NOT a object.  In the meantime _db IS a object of the type DbContext. so this would be simmilar to doing the following int i = int;.

so I guess the first thing id like to know is: do you want to be able to get an object/ should TEntity be an object OR do  you just to get the type of TEntity?
